# converting list to dictionary in a python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, load

I have a data in a list like below:

```
[
{'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Jeanette', 'last_name': 'Penddreth', 'email': 'jpenddreth0@census.gov', 'gender': 'Female', 'ip_address': '26.58.193.2'}, 
{'id': 2, 'first_name': 'Giavani', 'last_name': 'Frediani', 'email': 'gfrediani1@senate.gov', 'gender': 'Male', 'ip_address': '229.179.4.212'}, 
{'id': 3, 'first_name': 'Noell', 'last_name': 'Bea', 'email': 'nbea2@imageshack.us', 'gender': 'Female', 'ip_address': '180.66.162.255'}, 
{'id': 4, 'first_name': 'Willard', 'last_name': 'Valek', 'email': 'wvalek3@vk.com', 'gender': 'Male', 'ip_address': '67.76.188.26'}
]
```

I am loading the data into the dynamoDb. It is failing with the error `type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>: ParamValidationError`.

How do I convert the above list into a dictionary?

**EDIT** Code used:

```
import boto3
import json

s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb=boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context): 
    bucket=event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'] 
    json_filename=event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object=s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_filename)
    jsonFileReader=json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDictionary=json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    table=dynamodb.Table('EMPLOYEE_DETAILS') 
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDictionary) 
    return 'Done'
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what your goal is? That list already is a list of dictionaries. Do you just want to concatenate the dicts into a single one?

Comment: Iterate through the items in your list (these items are **dictionaries**), and add them one by one.

Comment: Hi Ollie, many thanks for the quick revert.

Comment: I am loading the JSON file data from S3 to dynamo DB. I am using the below code.

Comment: import boto3
import json

s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb=boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    bucket=event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_filename=event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object=s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_filename)
    jsonFileReader=json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDictionary=json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    table=dynamodb.Table('EMPLOYEE_DETAILS')
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDictionary)
    return 'Done'

Comment: But if my jason file is having more than one record/object in it , the code is failing,as the putitem argument (Item)should be a class dict.

Comment: can u pls correct me if any thing change is required please?

Comment: Please edit your question and add this code. It is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: import boto3
import json

s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb=boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    bucket=event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_filename=event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object=s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_filename)
    jsonFileReader=json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDictionary=json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    table=dynamodb.Table('EMPLOYEE_DETAILS')
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDictionary)
    return 'Done'

Comment: {import boto3
import json

s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb=boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    bucket=event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_filename=event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object=s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_filename)
    jsonFileReader=json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDictionary=json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    table=dynamodb.Table('EMPLOYEE_DETAILS')
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDictionary)
    return 'Done' 
 }

Comment: sorry im unable to put in a proper format..pls help

Comment: HI Zinki, i guess it will solve my problem if i can able to concatenate and made a single dictionary . From the error log we could see that the Item class should be a dictionary . Can u pls suggest how can we achieve this?

Comment: Friends, i thnik now you can see it in a readable format?

Comment: Friends kinldy let me know if any inputs is further needed. Your help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `dynamodb`, but I imagine this will work. If your JSON is a list, then you need to iterate through the items in your list, adding each one to the table.

Replace the line:

```
table.put_item(Item=jsonDictionary)
```

with:

```
if type(jsonDictionary) == type([]):
    # It is a list - iterate through it
    for item in jsonDictionary:
        table.put_item(Item=item) 
else:
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDictionary)
```

Comment: Hello Ollie, it worked for me:) great !! Thanks a lot. Thank you for everyone for your valuble inputs. Cheers :)

Comment: Friends, Ollie ,is there any optimized solution to achieve this ? Like using list comprehension or zip using the python ? I'm novice to python . Can anyone help on this please ?

Comment: I can't think of any way to optimise it. Regardless of how you try to "optimise" it, you would still have to check if the JSON is a list, and if it is, iterate through those items.

Comment: okay Ollie. If suppose I am having a huge data file say 1 billion coming form source and i have a lambda funtion written in python to insert the data to the DB. Here  the drawback is the lambda function runs max of 300 seconds i,e for 5 minutes. in this case how can i optimise my python code to handle this? can we do bilk insertion or batch insert in python? I ma novice to it. Really appreciate if i get some help to sort this issue out. Many thanks:)

Comment: I don't know enough about `dynamodb` to answer that question sorry. Maybe create a new question for this.